# Mootools: Selecting an element with a space in one of its attribute

Tags: javascript, select, mootools, element, spaces

I want to do something like this:

```
var sp = el.getElement('option[value="Option With Spaces"]');
```

ie. Select an option element in a select drop down box that so happens to have spaces in the value field.

Mootools doesn't seem to like it. I can't find any documentation that can resolve this.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

*Version*: Mootools 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your old mootools 1.11, you need to use filter if your attribute/property is not a single word (even - breaks it so data-nnn will fail as well).

```
var el = document.getElement("select");
var sp = el.getElements("option").filter(function(el) {
    return el.getProperty("value") == "foo bar";
}).getLast() || null;

console.log(sp);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dimitar/3AEZA/1/

Comment: Mr Dimitar the mootools master strikes again :) Thanks.

Comment: So instead of the above i'm now doing this: el.getElement('option[class=option_with_paces]');

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 value="Option\ With\ Spaces"
```

Comment: in 1.11 it won't work. in fact, even `div[data-id]` won't work.